# putting logic in routes file to dynamically match the controller end point in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, routes

I am having a problem that is, i want to dynamically redirect to appropriate path based on the user's role.
I have two model Say fan and artist.
I am using omniauth gem to sign up with `facebook`. If the user want to sign up with facebook as a Fan then I would like to redirect redirect that user to `fans/new`.
And if the user want to sign up as an Artist i would like to redirect to `artists/new` action.so

in routes file i should be something like below:

```
get 'auth/:provider/callback' => 'fan or artist's controller's new action based on the user's type '
```

Please help me guys i have no idea how to get the user's type in routes file.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put logic in routes because they are executed during the server startup.

I suggest to create a callback method in the users controller (or any controller that makes sense) that loads the current user and redirects accordingly.

You will have an extra redirect that will hurt performance. But login process performance is not usually an issue.